# QTabBar neither expands totally nor spaces tabs equally

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qtabwidget, qtabbar

I want the tabbar to expand over the empty space until the right. And best would be if all tabs had the same width. I don't know how to do that as my stylesheets don't work and I can't find an option in the docs.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import sys

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setFixedSize(600,500)

        self.tabBar=QTabBar(self)
        self.tabBar.setStyleSheet("QTabBar{width:400px;}")
        self.tabBar.setExpanding(True)

        self.layout=QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabBar)

        self.tabBar.addTab("Kontext Menu")
        self.tabBar.addTab("Settings in detail")
        self.tabBar.addTab("Help and tips")
        self.tabBar.addTab("About")
        self.tabBar.addTab("Credits")

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    sd=Main()
    app.exec()
```

[image]

I have the idea, as the dialog shall have fixed size, that one can calculate eachs tab width as Totalwidth/(Amount of Tabs), but still I don't know how to tell each tab its width...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand the tabs by using `void  setExpanding(bool enabled)`. See the documentation for details:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qtabbar.html#expanding-prop

Also, you will need to use the proper style syntax because you seem to lack the proper scope, i.e. the "::tab" part.

Also, you would need to set the style sheet on the `QTabWidget` itself as opposed to `QTabBar`. It may be a bit weird at first, but that is the correct way of achieving what you wish to have.

Here you can find the the code you should write:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import sys

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setFixedSize(600,500)

        self.tabBar=QTabBar(self)
        self.tabBar.setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab{width:400px;}")
        self.tabBar.setExpanding(True)

        self.layout=QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabBar)

        self.tabBar.addTab("Kontext Menu")
        self.tabBar.addTab("Settings in detail")
        self.tabBar.addTab("Help and tips")
        self.tabBar.addTab("About")
        self.tabBar.addTab("Credits")

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    sd=Main()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: It is working when I change `self.myQTabWidget`to `self.tabBar`. I thought the `::` are only in Qt-Syntax, but not for python...